# How to access array with boolean operation inside iteration in MQL4?

Tags: quantitative-finance, algorithmic-trading, mql4, metatrader4, forex

I'm able to get the value of Moving Average from Shift 1 to Shift n (n = amount of bars) and shows their value with Alert every 5 minute bar, but when I added the 'if (Direction == "Up")' and so on, the code shows last shift value only and hit '`break`'. The most important is, I can't use them into a boolean operations.

I want the code to show `Alert()` when values of `EMA` are rising up orderly, and vice versa (for a <kbd>**"Trend Down"**</kbd>). Whenever one of their value vary (one or more bars have higher or lower value than the others), then it's <kbd>"**No trend**"</kbd>.

Let's say amount of `TrendBar` is more than 5 bars; [] array is Bar Shift.

The algorithm for <kbd>**"Trend Up"**</kbd> is:

*if Slow[n] <= Slow[...] <= Slow[3] <= Slow[2] <= Slow[1] then true*

*else false*

```
int TrendBar    = 5,
    SlowPeriod  = 14;

void OnTick()
{
    if (NewBar(PERIOD_M5) == true) 
    {
        if (MA("Up", PERIOD_M5) == true) Alert ("Trend Up good");
        else if (MA("Up", PERIOD_M5) == false) Alert ("Trend Up bias");
        else Alert ("No Trend");
    }
}

bool MA(string Direction, int TF)
{
    double Slow[];
    ArrayResize(Slow, TrendMinDurationBar + 1);

    for (int i = TrendBar; i > 1; i--)
        {
            Slow[i] = NormalizeDouble(iMA(Symbol(), TF, SlowPeriod, 0, MODE_EMA, PRICE_OPEN, i), Digits);
            Alert("DataSlow" + (string)i + ": " + DoubleToStr(Slow[i], Digits));
            if (Direction == "Up")
            {
                if (Slow[i] <= Slow[i-1]) return(true);
                else if (Slow[i] > Slow[i-1]) {return(false); break;}
            }
        }
    return(false);
}

bool NewBar(int TF)
{
    static datetime lastbar = 0;
    datetime curbar = iTime(Symbol(), TF, 0);

    if (lastbar != curbar)
        {
            lastbar = curbar; 
            return(true);
        }
    else return(false);
}
```

When I run the code, it only shows `Alert( "Trend Up bias" )`. It means the code always hit '`break`' when iteration starts. It doesn't care whether the trend is in real trending up (all MA values in `Slow[]` array are orderly up) or not.

Q1: How to make the code work?

Q2: How to write correct code for accessing array with Boolean operations inside iteration?

Q3: What is the solution, please?

Answer (score 0):

### Summary:

> Q1: How to make the code work?

**A1**: Rewrite the iteration `for`-loop so as not to exit instantly in the first loop
<sub>( ref. the illustrated iteration flow / barrier below )</sub>

> Q2: How to write correct code for accessing array with Boolean operations inside iteration?

**A2**: There is no such problem at all. If possible, always avoid testing array values, before being assigned some value
<sub>( ref. the trap below )</sub>

> Q3: What is the solution, please?

**A3**: Repair the ill-formed `for`-loop + always assign a meaningful value into a variable before using it's value in further processing or comparison.

---

### How the algorithmisation may approach the unambiguous part of the features:

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                      MQL4 strict |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
#property strict              // MQL4 compilation mode { strict }

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                   a global-scope |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
bool     aTrendUpGTprev[],    // MQL4 dynamic array
         aTrendDnLTprev[];    // MQL4 dynamic array

int      TrendBar    =  5,
         SlowPeriod  = 14;

void     OnInit()
{        ArraySetAsSeries( aTrendDnLTprev, True );  // MQL4 Reference / Array Functions / ArraySetAsSeries 
         ArraySetAsSeries( aTrendUpGTprev, True );
}

bool     isNewBar( const int TF = PERIOD_CURRENT )
{        
         static datetime lastBar = EMPTY;
                datetime currBar = iTime( _Symbol, TF, 0 );

         if (    lastBar != currBar )               // .TEST
         {       lastBar  = currBar;                // .UPD
                 updateMA( TF );                    // .UPD
                 return( true );                    // .RET .T.
         }
         return( false );                           // .RET .F.
}

void     updateMA( const int TF = PERIOD_CURRENT )
{
         static bool    isFirstCall = True;
         static double  SlowMA_0,
                        SlowMA_1;

         if (  isFirstCall )                    // .TEST
         {     isFirstCall = False;             // .SET / LOCK FOREVER
            // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // INITIAL PRE-FILL FOR ANY-DEPTH TREND-CALCULUS
            // SHUFFLE-LOGIC LATCH-MOV PRINCIPALLY AVOIDS ANY-DEPTH RE-CALCULATION(S) - COMPUTATIONALLY EFFICIENT

               SlowMA_0 = NormalizeDouble( iMA( _Symbol,
                                                TF,
                                                SlowPeriod,
                                                0,
                                                MODE_EMA,
                                                PRICE_OPEN, // OPEN ?
                                                TrendBar
                                                ),
                                           Digits           // no need to Normalize here, as the values do not enter any XTO
                                           );
               for ( int iii = TrendBar - 1; iii > 0, iii-- )
               {     SlowMA_1 = SlowMA_0;
                     SlowMA_0 = SlowMA_0 = NormalizeDouble( iMA( _Symbol, TF, SlowPeriod, 0, MODE_EMA, PRICE_OPEN, iii ), Digits ); // no need to Normalize here, as the values do not enter any XTO
                     aTrendUpGTprev[iii] = (  SlowMA_0 >= SlowMA_1 );   // bi-state { True | False }
                     aTrendDnLTprev[iii] = (  SlowMA_0 <= SlowMA_1 );   // bi-state { True | False }
               }
         }

      // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      // SHUFFLE-LOGIC LATCH-MOV PRINCIPALLY AVOIDS ANY-DEPTH RE-CALCULATION(S)  - COMPUTATIONALLY EFFICIENT
      // PROTECTED FROM DESYNC/ARTIFACTS FROM RE-ENTRY(-IES) WITHIN THE SAME BAR - SAFE-MODE

         static datetime lastBar = EMPTY;
                datetime currBar = iTime( _Symbol, TF, 0 );

         if (    lastBar != currBar )              // .TEST
         {       lastBar  = currBar;               // .UPD
                 SlowMA_1 = SlowMA_0;              // .MOV [1] << [0]
                 SlowMA_0 = SlowMA_0 = NormalizeDouble( iMA( _Symbol, TF, SlowPeriod, 0, MODE_EMA, PRICE_OPEN, 0 ), Digits ); // .NEW [0]
                 aTrendUpGTprev[0] = (  SlowMA_0 >= SlowMA_1 );         // bi-state { True | False }
                 aTrendDnLTprev[0] = (  SlowMA_0 <= SlowMA_1 );         // bi-state { True | False }
         }

      // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      // MQL4 ( "new" MQL4 ) requirement to return even from a void fun() >>> MQL4 Reference / Updated MQL4
         return( NULL );
}

void     OnTick()
{
         if (  isNewBar( PERIOD_M5 ) )              // returns bool value per-se
         {  
            // if       (   MA( "Up", PERIOD_M5 ) ) Alert ( "Trend Up good" );   // Either this
            // else if  (  !MA( "Up", PERIOD_M5 ) ) Alert ( "Trend Up bias" );   // or this.
            // else                                 Alert ( "No Trend" );        // This is an un-reachable state within above defined logic
            // ----------------------------------------------------------------- // --------------------------------------------------------
                                                    // There is no principal chance
                                                    // to get a tri-state logic
                                                    // under one boolean var

               bool  isUP = aTrendUpGTprev[TrendBar];
               bool  isDN = aTrendDnLTprev[TrendBar];

               for ( int iii = TrendBar - 1; iii > 0; iii-- )
               {
                     isUP &= aTrendUpGTprev[iii];
                     isDN &= aTrendDnLTprev[iii];
               }
               if (  isUP )  Alert ( "Trend Up good" );  // if Slow[n] <= Slow[...] <= Slow[3] <= Slow[2] <= Slow[1] then true
               if (  isDN )  Alert ( "Trend Dn good" );

         }
}
```

---

### Problem is not an access to Array `cell[i]` from inside `for` loop

As given above, your code **as-is** does not meet what you strive to do.

```
bool MA( const string Direction, const int TF )
{
     double       Slow[];
     ArrayResize( Slow, TrendMinDurationBar + 1 );

     for ( int  i  = TrendBar; i > 1; i-- )
     {     Slow[i] = NormalizeDouble( iMA( _Symbol, TF, SlowPeriod, 0, MODE_EMA, PRICE_OPEN, i ),
                                      Digits
                                      );
        // Alert( "DataSlow" + (string)i + ": " + DoubleToStr( Slow[i], Digits ) );

           if (  Direction == "Up" )
           {
                 if      ( Slow[i] <= Slow[i-1] ) return( true  );
                 else if ( Slow[i] >  Slow[i-1] ) return( false );
           }
    }
    return( false );
}
```

It starts to iterate over an `i`-range `( 5, 4, 3, 2 )` in **`bool MA()`**

and test a sequence of comparisons:

**only in an `"Up"`-case:**

`[5]<=[4] |-> RET .T.`, _____________ either this

`[5]> [4] |-> RET .F.`, _____________     or this **is** & **must be** a reason for **`RET {.T. | .F.}`**

. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ code **never** gets past this

`[4]<=[3] |-> RET .T.`,

`[4]> [3] |-> RET .F.`,

`[3]<=[2] |-> RET .T.`,

`[3]> [2] |-> RET .F.`

You might already noticed, that **dynamic** arrays in `MQL4` do not have initialised value known, the more after `ArrayResize()`.

This makes the conditions `{ [5]<=[4] | [5]> [4] }` fairly vulnerable to issues out of your control, as your code has assigned a value into `Slow[5]` but **not** into `[4]` yet and there you go.

Dynamic array memory-allocation / resize **lottery side-effects expose** your code to **a principally uncontrollable value**, accessed in `[4]` in both comparisons `{ [5]<=[4] | [5]> [4] }`, which in principle is anything else but the `iMA(...)`.

As your observations indicate the `[4]` being lower than an already assigned `iMA()` value into `[5]`, **you were sort of lucky** that the randomness of the un-initialised memory ( containing uncontrollable residual binary values ) contained **by no other means but just by chance** some residual-bitmap, that happily was interpreted as a IEEE-float32 number, lower than the calculated & stored `iMA()` value compared in cell `[5]` with.

---

**Update:**

### What would I do if I were to implement the idea?

After several hundred man*years in the `MQL4`-domain, `Technical Indicators` have taught us to rather spend some time to separate computationaly expensive parts from cheaper parts of the algo and focus the design tuning around the more expensive parts.

So:

rather think about avoiding a waste to re-calculate values already once computed a `static double Slow[]` would allow you to save the values once computed on a `NewBar()` event or use the same idea step forwards to save not the "tail" of `Slow[5..2]`, and re-compare them upon deciding in `[0]`, but produce & re-use not the `iMA()` 4B-values, but rather their already made pair-wise comparisons, which solely decide the actual return value:

`static bool aTrendUpPrevGT[];`

`static bool aTrendDnPrevLT[];`

which will re-articulate the `if MA()` to update just the recent bar step
and

```
return (  aTrendUpPrevGT[5]
       && aTrendUpPrevGT[4]
       && aTrendUpPrevGT[3]
       && aTrendUpPrevGT[2]
          )
```

<sub>A proper use of `ArraySetAsSeries()` and correct indexing steps are obvious to be adapted</sub>

Comment: I get the picture but I still don't get it. Let's say, Slow[5] is 1.1230 and Slow[4] is 1.1231, then the code will run `Slow[i] <= Slow[i-1]` then return true, right? and after that, the code will not run `Slow[i] > Slow[i-1]` and give false, right? Why the code also run the second condition while it's not correct?

So what codes do I should write down inside the loop just to shows the trend is up (MA values orderly up for n bars)? Do I need to get rid the array? Again, what codes do I have to use if you say I need to get rid array?

Comment: As you have proposed: " Let's say, `Slow[5]` is `1.1230` and `Slow[4]` **is `1.1231`,"** kindly notice, you do **not have** any known value inside `Slow[4]` at the very moment, you store the value of `1.230` into `Slow[5]`. This is the trap.

Comment: It is a trap. I noticed now, the first iteration only know value on MA shift 5. About your last update, are you suggesting I have to write down all `aTrendUpPrev[n]`? What about if n is more than 5, let's say, hundred? :(

Comment: As answered in the [Update] - a proper use of ArraySetAsSeries() will allow you to keep all these values in a stepwise growing array in parallel to the TOHLCV time-series. Another way would be to move this part of the processing into a Custom Indicator. **Anyway, I am glad you have realised the root cause of the problem you were asking about.**

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little bit late. I'm just glad too whenever you wrote down 'trap'. Anyhow, do you mind give me some example using `ArraySetAsSeries()` for my case above especially dealing with `if Slow[n] <= Slow[...] <= Slow[3] <= Slow[2] <= Slow[1] then true` line and so on?

Comment: I'm still not satisfied with the all answers provided. It's true the core problem is known already but the main question still remain unanswered, which is how to write code so I will have Trend Up with `Slow[n] <= Slow[...] <= Slow[3] <= Slow[2] <= Slow[1]` algorithm, especially with your solution that brings up `ArraySetAsSeries()`? Given the many solutions that can be offered, I only need a straight answer. Right now, I just don't need another suggestion, please. Just forget about `ArraySetAsSeries()`, I won't open another new question until this issue well solved. Hope you understand.

Comment: Well.. still need the answer, all replies above regarding to my question definitely only suggestion. It's a 'trap' if someone believe the question above has the answer. It's still an open question.